# Make android print bypassing print dialog

Tags: android, protocols, canon-sdk

My goal is to develop an Android app that can print an image directly without prompting the user for print settings. I want the app to send the necessary data to the printer and initiate the printing process automatically. As the sole user of the app, I aim to streamline the printing experience and eliminate unnecessary prompts to make the app faster and more efficient. Im specifically interested in obtaining the data structure required to send to a Canon Pixma TS3522 printer to achieve this goal.

What is the communication protocol used by the Canon Pixma TS3522 printer to receive print data?

2. What is the specific data structure that needs to be sent to the printer for successful printing?
3. What is the recommended image format to send to the Pixma TS3522 printer? Do standard formats like JPEG or PNG work?
4. Are there any size or resolution limitations that should be considered when sending print data to the printer?
5. Does the printer require any additional headers or metadata in the print data besides the actual image itself?
6. Are there any special settings that need to be considered on the Pixma TS3522 printer before sending print data?
7. Are there any specific scripting or data flow recommendations or requirements for successful printing?
8. Does the Pixma TS3522 printer support any specific Page Description Language (PDL) such as PCL or PostScript?
9. Are there any libraries, SDKs, or resources provided by Canon to facilitate communication with the Pixma TS3522 printer?
10. Where can I find official documentation or additional resources about the Canon Pixma TS3522 printer and its communication protocol?

Comment: Please read: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/295004) and [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/295004)